# Heroku/Memcache/Rack::Cache Stats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, memcached

I am trying to wrap my brain around Rack::Cache, Rails 3.2, Memcache, and Heroku. I think I've got it all working together, as outlined here: http://myownpirateradio.com/2012/01/01/getting-heroku-cedar-and-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-to-play-nicely-together/

All that said, I am unsure if Memcached is actually doing what it should. Is there any way to get stats on Memcached or to see if a request was cached by Memcached? I put the current time on a page, and can see that it is getting cached (headers look good too), but how do I know it is all working with Memcached, as opposed to the file store?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get stats on memcached by doing:

```
$ heroku run console
Running console attached to terminal... up, run.1
Loading production environment (Rails 3.1.3)
irb(main):001:0> Rails.cache.stats
Dalli/SASL authenticating as app590983%40heroku.com
Dalli/SASL: Authenticated
=> {"mc5.ec2.northscale.net:11211"=>{"evictions"=>"0", "curr_items"=>"627",
    "total_items"=>"1257", "bytes"=>"2294318", "reclaimed"=>"0", 
    "engine_maxbytes"=>"5242880", "bucket_conns"=>"2", "pid"=>"319", 
    "uptime"=>"6710022", "time"=>"1330731177", "version"=>"1.4.4_207_g19c6b9e", 
    "libevent"=>"1.4.11-stable", "pointer_size"=>"64", 
    "rusage_user"=>"34354.590000", "rusage_system"=>"31381.520000", 
    "daemon_connections"=>"10", "curr_connections"=>"1211", 
    "total_connections"=>"14127919", "connection_structures"=>"1764", 
    "cmd_get"=>"9476", "cmd_set"=>"1257", "cmd_flush"=>"0", "auth_cmds"=>"24", 
    "auth_errors"=>"0", "get_hits"=>"8093", "get_misses"=>"1383", 
    "delete_misses"=>"0", "delete_hits"=>"0", "incr_misses"=>"0", 
    "incr_hits"=>"0", "decr_misses"=>"0", "decr_hits"=>"0", "cas_misses"=>"0", 
    "cas_hits"=>"0", "cas_badval"=>"0", "bytes_read"=>"21983909", 
    "bytes_written"=>"85267718", "limit_maxbytes"=>"67108864", 
    "rejected_conns"=>"0", "threads"=>"4", "conn_yields"=>"0"}}
```

PS: I think you might need to be using the Dalli gem for this to work, but that is the recommended client anyway.

You can also run `Rails.cache.class` to see which backend is Rails using.

Comment: Thanks! Know of any resources for understanding the output of Rails.cache.stats?

Comment: Not really, most of the keys seem fairly self descriptive. If there's anything specific that you'd like to know, you can just post a question.

Comment: I have a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115187/what-exactly-does-the-memcached-size-limit-represent-with-file-system-entitystor) - this didn't quite get me to an answer... any help would be appreciated! @Jakub-hampl

Comment: @MattFordham This helped me a lot http://www.pal-blog.de/entwicklung/perl/memcached-statistics-stats-command.html