# What exactly does the Memcached size limit represent with file system entitystore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, memcached

Good afternoon,

I have Memcached hooked up in my app on Heroku.  The limit for the free managed plan is 5MB for Memcached and 25MB for Memcachier.  Being new to pretty much everything, I was just hoping for clarification of exactly what this represents.

I have the DalliStore set up in my config file, and the typical options set up for Rack::Cache.  My metastore is in Memcache and the entitiy store is set up on the filesystem.

Questions:

1. Does this mean that my 5/25MB limit is only being used by the meta information that I am storing about each cache fragment?  This would mean that I'd be able to store a ton of information on just the free plans?
2. What exactly is the breakdown / story between Rack::Cache and Memcache (via Dalli store?)  Do they serve different purposes?  Are they doing the same thing?  i.e. is the following code redundant

   `config.cache_store = :dalli_store`

and

```
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {
  :verbose      => true,
  :metastore    => Dalli::Client.new,
  :entitystore  => 'file:tmp/cache/rack/body',
  :allow_reload => false
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been wrestling with similar issues.

First of all, let's get our terminology straight.

- **Memcached**: a process running on a server somewhere (d is for daemon) that actually stores key-value pairs in memory.
- **cache_store**: Rails cache storage (`Rails.cache`) with a single API which can be configured to use different Ruby software implementations. One setting for `config.cache_store` is `:memory_store` to use an in-memory implementation. Another setting is `:dalli_store` that specifies using the dalli gem, which under the hood makes a possibly-remote connection to your memcached server.
- **Dalli Store**: I assume you mean the Rails cache backed by the dalli gem, which physically stores values in memcached.
- **Rack::Cache**: Rack middleware that inserts headers (Expires, Cache-Control, ETag, etc.) into your HTTP responses, and also acts as a reverse proxy cache, handling requests before they hit the Rails stack when possible. See [website](http://rtomayko.github.com/rack-cache/).

In order for Rack::Cache to handle requests before they hit the Rails stack and the rest of your app, it must store responses + metadata somewhere. Where it stores things are configured by the `config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = { ... }` setting.

Notice, this is a *different* setting from `config.cache_store = :dalli_store`. They don't have to be related. I think this is where a lot of confusion comes from. In practice, though, we may want them both to use memcached, which means using the dalli implementation. However, they each have their own `Dalli::Client` instance. (Also, your session_store could be related, but doesn't have to be.)

The Heroku cedar stack has an [ephemeral file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) that cannot be shared among dynos. However, Heroku themselves [recommend using tmp file storage with Rack::Cache](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-static-assets-rails31) for the `entitystore` only, with memcached used for the `metastore`.

As for what actually gets stored in the Rack::Cache metastore, these are the docs from [rack-cache v1.2 `Rack::Cache::MetaStore`](https://github.com/rtomayko/rack-cache/blob/1.2/lib/rack/cache/metastore.rb#L8) class:

```
The MetaStore is responsible for storing meta information about a
request/response pair keyed by the request's URL.

The meta store keeps a list of request/response pairs for each canonical
request URL. A request/response pair is a two element Array of the form:
  [request, response]

The +request+ element is a Hash of Rack environment keys. Only protocol
keys (i.e., those that start with "HTTP_") are stored. The +response+
element is a Hash of cached HTTP response headers for the paired request.
```

So to answer your question, HTTP request headers and HTTP response headers are stored in the Rack::Cache metastore. On the other hand, the Rack::Cache entitystore stores entire response bodies (i.e. HTML).

Since [you can't use page caching reliably on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies#page-caching), this means you might be using action caching and fragment caching. Action and fragment caching use your Rails cache store (not rack cache). But if you've set them both to physically use the same memcached server, they'll both contribute to memory use. Action and partial caching store the actual HTML.

To get more insight of your actual usage, if you're using memcachier run the following command to open up an analytics dashboard in your browser.

```
heroku addons:open memcachier
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541817/heroku-memcache-rackcache-stats) for more info about getting memcached stats.

Comment: Jonathan - thanks for this. Although it has been ages since I asked this question (and it was answered), your answer addresses my original issues far better.  If only you had found this in the spring!  Upvote/accepted.

Comment: Your response did bring up one more question. What happens if Rack::Cache stores metadata in memcached (e.g. Memcachier) and the response body in `/tmp` in Heroku, and then `/tmp` is cleared?  I'm assuming Rack::Cache is smart enough to not balk on the filestore being cleared out behind it.

Comment: That's correct. When something is found in the metastore but not in the entitystore, Rack::Cache does the right thing by triggering a cache miss. The relavant source methods are [Rack::Cache::Context#lookup](https://github.com/rtomayko/rack-cache/blob/1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb#L163) and [Rack::Cache::MetaStore#lookup](https://github.com/rtomayko/rack-cache/blob/1.2/lib/rack/cache/metastore.rb#L28).

Comment: Heroku [no longer recommend using the file store](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-rails31#handling-multiple-dynos) for storing entity data due to the reason you mention in your post, that the `/tmp` filesystem is not available to all of your dynos.

Comment: in the same article: "Another option would be to setup each dyno to use a dyno specific prefix on keys for the MetaStore, keeping each dyno’s Rack::Cache independent."  how would one create and use this specific prefix key?

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is not so easy to answer.

First of all, you will likely not be storing anything on the Heroku filesystem, <del>as it is not writeable</del>. Therefore you should store everything in Memcache. So on the free plan you will store 5/25mb of data including both entities and metadata.

As the docs say (for the Cedar stack):

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During its lifetime the dyno can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files it writes are visible to any other dyno (including other dynos in the application) and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted.

Therefore, yes using the filesystem seems fairly viable, especially if you are using a single dyno.

Regarding the distinction between Rack::Cache and Memcache: Memcache is a server that stores key/value pairs with some additional nice properties in memory. The `config.cache_store = :dalli_store` configures `Rails.cache` which is an abstraction over the different caching mechanisms that one could use. It is general and you can use it for arbitrary key/value storage, action and fragment caching.

Rack::Cache on the other hand is a replacement for Varnish and allows you to cache whole requests.

Comment: So if using both cache_store : dalli and Rack:: Cache, what will store action cached pages? And what will store the results of a Rails.cache.fetch {...}? [This article from Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-static-assets-rails31) talks about using Rack cache as well as Dalli... And with the entity store under /tmp which would infer only the meta information being stored on Memcached...  (Don't know if I am overthinking this, I'm just concerned about what I can store in a Rack.cache.fetch call)

Comment: Action cached pages will be stored in the `Rails.cache`. I don't recommend storing anything in `/tmp` since anything in there may be deleted between requests.

Comment: Thanks Jakub - I've accepted this answer as I think I'm getting this sorted out in my mind.  I suppose 25MB doesn't go that far if it needs to hold the metadata in addition to the HTML fragments themselves.  At the very least I suppose I should be careful about storing active record objects in the cache as the 25MB will probably get eaten up awful fast!

Comment: Depends a lot how big an app you're running. The 5mb is probably good if you have less then a 100 active users (my current setup for an in-house app).

Comment: For the Cedar stack it is actually recommended by the heroku people to use the filestore as the entity store and memcached as the meta store: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-static-assets-rails31 Another thing I'm wondering about is why would anyone not use the Memcachier add on instead of Memcached as Memcachier offers 25 instead of only 5MB storage.

Comment: So actually on the Heroku cedar stack the filesystem IS writable. Maybe this should be added to the answer.

Comment: I had the same thoughts Nico.  Not sure if there is any difference in the reliability, but I don't see any reason to not use Memcachier, seeing as you get 5x the space for free.  If you look up their pricing plans, they also appear to be cheaper in general than the Couchbase offering.

Comment: @Nico one remaining question in my mind is about the filestore as entity store.  How can you use a Memcached process for a metastore, but have your entitystore in a filesystem that is independent to each dyno (i.e. not sharable amongst dynos)?  Does memcached somehow separate the metainfo of separate dyno's caches?

Comment: Sorry to barge in but what's the difference between entity store and meta store?

Comment: Metastore is made up of many small key values, which memcached excels at storing and retrieving.
Entitystore is the cached content content itself (e.g. your response to the browser), which the filesystem is better suited for.